# VBA can't find emails in outlook using .Find

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created a macro that works great on my computer. When I upload and run it on another computer, it can't find any emails.

```
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


            subj = "Test email"

                Set olMi = olItms.Find("[Subject] = " & Chr(34) & subj & Chr(34))
              If Not (olMi Is Nothing) Then
                        For Each olAtt In olMi.Attachments
              Else
                  ' ends up here everytime
```

I sent myself an email called "Test email" and I can see it in my outlook inbox but my macro can never find it( on any computer I upload the macro to). However when I run the program on the original computer I wrote the program on, it works fine. Not really sure what the issue is.

Comment: Looking at the code it appears it's ok. I'd test to make sure the Subject is in fact "Test Email". Try iterating over each mail item and print out the subject line to be sure, it doesn't seem like it is finding it.

Comment: What is the different between computer? how did you transfer the code from your computer to the other?

Comment: @Om3r - I emailed it . I also placed it in drop box to access it through multiple computers. The only real difference is one computer is a dell and the other is an HP. The OS's are the same and Microsoft Office 2013 is on both.

Comment: UPDATE: I have checked outlook security settings for macros, all references match up in excel and it still cant find an email with my vba macro. I even started a project from scratch to test it and still nothing. Really unsure of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search on the PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT MAPI property:

```
set olMi = olItms.Find("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" = '" & subj & "'")
```

Comment: Thanks. My experience with VBA is a bit limited. What exactly is this line of code doing exactly?

Comment: It is searching for the PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT property instead of PR_SUBJECT (which is not indexed). Since PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT is not exposed through OOM, you need to specify the property DASL property name in double quotes and prefix the query by "@SQL=".